# I want to make my website open source but I have a file with DB credentials

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, git, github, next.js

I made a website with NextJS that I'd like to make open source, but I have a .env file with read-only credentials to my DB.
I don't think it would be a huge issue to make those credentials public as I wouldn't mind people querying my DB, but it still seems risky and I'd rather not.
Keep in mind that I use Vercel to deploy the website, which gets the code from the git repo.

I've thought about cloning the private repo, deleting the .env file and making this new repo public, but that's not an ideal solution since I'd end up with two repos.

Comment: This `.env` file should be added to `.gitignore` and never commited

Comment: But then how will Vercel know the credentials?

Comment: Not from a file https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables you have to set the credentials in vercel

Comment: @GustavoMorais all hosting services will have a way to set environment variables for this purpose. If you rent a VM then you can set them from the command line. dotenv is for development only.

Comment: He did not ask how to remove it from git although it’s important. If you host your project in GitHub, maybe this will help you: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 0):

I assume your .env file has already been committed to the repo?

Add it to `.gitignore`, and use [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (usage instructions at that link) to delete the file from your repo. A normal delete will not work, as the file will still be in the git history. Using BFG, it'll be erased from the repo entirely.

Comment: But then how will Vercel know the credentials?

Comment: Note that GitHub will retain the original commits, including the password, forever unless you get GitHub support involved.